# Is the positive part of the Zariski decomposition of a big $\mathbb{R}$-divisor big?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, surfaces, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I can't understand why the positive part of the Zariski decomposition of a big class is itself big.  More concretely:
let $X$ be a smooth projective surface over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $N^1_{\mathbb{R}}(X)$ be the Néron-Severi space associated to $X$. Let $D$ be a big class in $N^1_{\mathbb{R}}(X)$ and let $D=P_D+N_D$ be its Zariski decomposition. Recall that $P_D$ is an effective, nef $\mathbb{R}$-divisor and $N_D=\sum_i a_i C_i$ is an effective, negative $\mathbb{R}$-divisor, where "negative" means that the Gram-matrix $(C_i \cdot C_j)_{i,j}$ is negative definite. Moreover it holds $P_D \cdot C_i=0$ for every $i$.
How to show that $P_D$ is a big $\mathbb{R}$-divisor? It should be an elementary fact, but I can't see it...

Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: What is your definition of big?

Comment: For me an $\mathbb{R}$-divisor $D$ is big if it can be written in the form $D=\sum_i a_iD_i$, where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ is positive and $D_i$ is integral and big.

Comment: As for integral big divisors, for me they are divisors of maximal Itaka dimension (following Lazarsfeld).

Comment: A nef divisor on an irreducible projective variety $X$ with $\dim X = n$ is big if and only if its **volume** $D^n$ is positive. Have you tried writing out $D^2 = (P_D - N_D)^2 > 0$ and applying what you know (namely that $P_D \cdot C_i = 0$ and the intersection properties of the $C_i$)?

Comment: Well, I tried this way and I get $D^2=P_D^2+N_D^2$ and now I know that $N_D^2<0$ and $P_D^2 \geq 0$, but I don't know how to go on from here. I should have that $P_D^2 > -N_D^2$ to get what wanted, but why is this true? Maybe I should look explicitily at the construction of the Zariski decomposition.

Comment: Assuming that $N_D^2$ is indeed strictly less than $0$ and that isn't a typo, I don't think you need anymore geometric input. Since $D^2 > 0$, we must have that $P_D^2 > |N_D^2| > 0$  hence $P_D$ is big (put differently, if $P_D^2 = 0$, which is the only thing we need to avoid, then $D^2$ would be strictly negative, being equal to $N_D^2$ in that case). And actually, if it is a typo and $N_D^2 \le 0$, then in the case that $N_D^2 = 0$ we again have $P_D^2 = D^2  > 0$.

Comment: But I am not assuming that $D$ is nef, so I don't know if $D^2>0$ (this is why I didn't understand well your comment before). Moreover the only case when $N_D^2=0$ is when $N_D=0$.

Comment: Moreover if $D$ is big and nef, then $D=P_D$. So $P_D$ is trivially big and nef.

Comment: Oh shoot, my apologies. I was checking my statements in some handwritten notes (http://people.math.harvard.edu/~bullery/math252notes/Section%2015_%20Big%20line%20bundles.pdf) and totally missed the $D$ nef hypothesis on the relevant result.

Comment: Dear @TabesBridges don't worry :). Thank you for your help and... if you are interested, you can find an answer here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377151/is-the-positive-part-of-the-zariski-decomposition-of-a-big-mathbbr-divisor